# why redirect to is not working in angular routing?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-router

here is my **routerModule** i want to redirect the blank (first page) should be the first child of the **Maincompoenent**. when is try it in browser it showing nothing but when i try **/web** it shows me that page.

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/web', pathMatch: 'full' },
{ 
path : '',
component : MainComponent,
children: [

  {
    path : 'web',
    loadChildren: './shop/shop.module#ShopModule'
  },
  { 
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: './pages/pages.module#PagesModule'
  },
  { 
    path: 'blog',
    loadChildren: './blog/blog.module#BlogModule'
  }
]
},
{ 
  path: '**', 
  redirectTo: 'web'
 }
];
```

here is shop module , i want redirect to first route and use as a main page of site

const routes: Routes = [

```
    { 
      path: '',

      component: HomeFiveComponent,

    },

    {
      path: 'left-sidebar/collection/:category',
      component: CollectionLeftSidebarComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'right-sidebar/collection/:category',
      component: CollectionRightSidebarComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'no-sidebar/collection/:category',
      component: CollectionNoSidebarComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'left-sidebar/product/:id',
      component: ProductLeftSidebarComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'right-sidebar/product/:id',
      component: ProductRightSidebarComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'no-sidebar/product/:id',
      component: ProductNoSidebarComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'col-left/product/:id',
      component: ProductColLeftComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'col-right/product/:id',
      component: ProductColRightComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'column/product/:id',
      component: ProductColumnComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'accordian/product/:id',
      component: ProductAccordianComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'left-image/product/:id',
      component: ProductLeftImageComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'right-image/product/:id',
      component: ProductRightImageComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'vertical/product/:id',
      component: ProductVerticalTabComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'search',
      component: SearchComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'wishlist',
      component: WishlistComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'compare',
      component: ProductCompareComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'cart',
      component: CartComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'checkout',
      component: CheckoutComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'checkout/success',
      component: SuccessComponent
    }
  ];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
 })
export class ShopRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: I think you cannot redirect directly to children, firstly you have to redirect to parent and then to that child component

Answer (score 2):

this might be an old question but you have a '/' in your redirect url you should remove that and it would work.

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'web', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

for others that may stumble on this question like me always make sure that the redirect is on top.

Answer (score 0):

I think this you need to specify where to **redirect** it in 'children'. [Here](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes) you find the redirect snippets. This may help you.

Comment: i added the shop module